# Installing Opera Mobile Emulator tar.gz files

Tags: command-line, tar

I am new here can anyone help me out!. How can i install a tar.gz file through the terminal. I've been trying to install the Opera Mobile Emulator.

Comment: You don't install a tar.gz it is a compressed archive, you must extract it, if you give me a link to the package, I will help you more.

Comment: Hello Mark! What you mean link? The download page i downloaded the file from?

Comment: Yes please, so I can see what is inside the tar.gz

Comment: http://www.opera.com/download/get.pl?sub=++++&id=35129&location=360&nothanks=yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install a `tar.gz`. It is a compressed file (like a .zip).

To extract the file from a terminal, download it (in this example, it will just be in your /home folder), and run

```
tar xvf Opera_Mobile_Emulator_12.1_Linux.tar.gz
```

Or you can right click it and choose <kbd>extract here</kbd>.

This will make a folder in /home called `Opera_Mobile_Emulator_12.1_Linux`, in this folder is an executable file (no install needed) called `opera-mobile-emulator-launcher`, double click this or run

```
cd ~/Opera_Mobile_Emulator_12.1_Linux
./opera-mobile-emulator-launcher
```

It should pop right up.

[Here is the manual for the `tar` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: Please accept the answer on the left if it helped you, so others can easily identify it.

Comment: @markkirby : ... just saw that you try to help new users as well ... so +1 for that ... ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox i always try to help new users, there what we get most, just careful of those dupes ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is named `filename.tar.gz`, use the command `tar xvzf filename.tar.gz`.  The `x` option means extract; the `v` option means to be verbose in reporting what the tar command is doing; the `z` option means the files were zipped; the `f` option means the filename will follow.

(If you're new to the terminal, here's a useful tip: start typing the filename and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  The terminal will auto-complete the name of the file you are typing.  If there are two or more possible completions, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice will show a list of possible completions.)

If the file is named `filename.tar`, omit the `z` in the command above:

```
tar xvf filename.tar.gz
```

If the file is named `filename.gz`, it is a zipped file that is NOT a `tar` archive.  Unzip it using the command `gunzip filename.gz`.

You say you are "installing" it; the above will just extract the files that are bundled up together (in what is called a "tarball").  If the file(s) inside the tarball are a software package, you will have more work to do to install the software.  Run the `file` command by typing `file filename` (where `filename` is the file that gets created from unpacking the tarball) to see what type of file `filename` is, and post the output in the comments below.  If it is just a directory, you might already have what you need and have no further work to do.